# New attributes are not showing up in django admin dashboard

Tags: django, django-models

Previously I was using my project with sqlite. Then started a new project copied the data from previous project and made some changes, and I'm using this with mysql.

This is my models.py(not full)

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q, F

class College(models.Model):
    CITY_CHOICES=[('BAN','Bangalore')]
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(choices=CITY_CHOICES,default='BAN',max_length=10)
    fest_nos=models.IntegerField()
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='college_pics')

    class Meta():
        db_table='college'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Organizer(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    phone=models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Fest(models.Model):
    FEST_CHOICES=[
        ('CUL','Cultural'),
        ('TEC','Technical'),
        ('COL','College'),
        ('SPO','Sports'),
    ]
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    clg_id=models.ForeignKey(College,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fest_type=models.CharField(choices=FEST_CHOICES,default='COL',max_length=10)
    fest_desc=models.TextField(default='This is a fest')
#below two field are not showing up in admin page
    start_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    event_nos=models.IntegerField()
    org_id=models.ManyToManyField(Organizer)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='fest_pics')
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = Q(end_date__gte=F('start_date')), 
                name = 'check_start_date',
            )
        ]
        db_table='fest'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The start_date and end_date attributes are the new ones added in this project. It was not there in the old one.
My admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import College, Event, Fest, Organizer, Participated

admin.site.register(College)
admin.site.register(Organizer)
admin.site.register(Fest)
admin.site.register(Event)
admin.site.register(Participated)
```

But in my admin dashboard, while adding new fests I'm not getting the option to add start and end date.

I made migrations once again, fake migrated etc. What to do?
Is check constraint under model fest causing this problem?

Comment: Both fields have `auto_now_add=True`, this makes them not editable and take the current datetime when an instance is created

Answer (score 1):

They fields won't show up on Django Admin because they have `auto_now_add=True` so, the user shouldn't touch them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `auto_now_add` field display in admin by using [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in the admin class(this only show the data, you still can't edit it because it's auto_now_add)

```
#register with a class to use
class FestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('start_date', 'end_date')

admin.site.register(Fest, FestAdmin)
```